# Using pam_succeed_if.so to allow passwordless su for a given group

Tags: users, password, authentication, pam

I have a service user `srvuser` and a group `maintainers`. How can I allow only group `maintainers` to become `srvuser` with `su` command? I tried editing `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = maintainers and user ingroup maintainers
```

But `and` is apparently not allowed in the conf file. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Just curious, why not use `sudo` which has a very simple way to do this?

Comment: Short answer would be weird requirements for sudoers file from security people. They didn't say anything about pam.d though ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the documentation of `pam_succeed_if` seems to indicate that it would support multiple conjunctions, so you'll need to do it outside the module.

If you were writing a `required` rule, it would be simple to combine them by creating two separate rules:

```
auth  required  pam_succeed_if.so user = srvuser
auth  required  pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup maintainers
```

But with a `sufficient` rule, as in one that terminates processing when a positive result is returned, this would not work, but turn into an *or* condition instead. But PAM supports a sort of flow control, allowing to skip some rules based on the return value of a previous module. See the [documentation here](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html).

This should flow through to the `pam_permit` rule as long as the `pam_succeed_if` modules return true, but skip to the following rules if they return anything but a `success`.

```
auth  [success=ok default=2]  pam_succeed_if.so user = srvuser
auth  [success=ok default=1]  pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup maintainers
auth  [success=done default=ignore]  pam_permit.so
... # other modules
```

As you can see, the syntax is horrible, and I would suggest testing the configuration before even trying to actually use it anywhere.

---

Of course, to allow members of a some group to run a process with the privileges of another user, you don't necessarily need `su`, `sudo` or PAM. 
With the usual file permissions, you could create a setuid binary, and only allow members of a given group to execute it:

```
# chown srvuser.maintainers ls
# chmod 4510 ls
# ls -l ls
-r-s--x--- 1 srvuser maintainers 118280 Mar 26 19:03 ls
```

The downside here is that unlike `su` and `sudo`, running a setuid binary is not logged anywhere, and that the setuid binary can be modified or deleted by processes running as the target user. To work around this, you could create a simple fixed-function wrapper program, to log the execution, `setuid` to the target, and then `exec` the actual command.